# I want to have a set of patches overlay onto an image and want to control their color range?

Tags: arrays, image, matlab, patch

I have a set of patches I am overlaying onto an image. The below patches draw a grid of boxes over the image. This works when I dont try and restrict the colormap range. But when I try and set it with caxis it does not allow me to use the array of hpatch as a handle. How can I get this to work? or is there a better approach then what I am doing? Also the image is grayscale but I would like the patches to use the jet colormap. Is this possible to do?

```
hFig = figure;
hAx = axes('Parent',hFig);

for i = 1:256
    hpatch(i) = patch([x2(i+17) x2(i+18) x2(i+1) x2(i)],[y2(i+17) y2(i+18) y2(i+1) y2(i)],[0 0 0 0],'Parent',hAx, 'FaceColor','flat','CData',cdata(i),'CDataMapping','scaled', 'FaceAlpha',(0.5));
end
caxis(hpatch,[0 25])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one problem: the [colormap](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/colormap.html) is a [*figure*-level property](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/figure_props.html#Colormap). When using the [CAXIS](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/caxis.html) function, you have to pass it an *axes handle*, not a patch handle, and specify a range that determines how the color data values in that set of axes are mapped to the colormap.

If your axes have an [indexed-color image](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/creating_plots/f2-10709.html#f2-155) or other objects with their [`'CDataMapping'` property](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/patch_props.html#CDataMapping) set to `'direct'` or `'scaled'`, then it may get quite messy trying to make one colormap to accommodate them all. You would have to concatenate their colormaps into one to use for the figure, then adjust their color value indices accordingly. Changing the scaling for any one object would be more involved than just using [CAXIS](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/caxis.html): you'd have to modify the corresponding section of the colormap for that object or modify its colormap indices stored in the [`'CData'`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/patch_props.html#CData) property.

However, you can simplify the problem by making sure only one object (or related set of objects) uses the colormap, setting all the other objects to use fixed RGB values for their `'CData'`. Since you mention that your image is grayscale, it would be best to make it a [Truecolor (i.e. RGB) image](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/creating_plots/f2-10709.html#f2-12468) (if it isn't already) so that only your patches use the colormap. Here's how you can convert your image:

- If the image you're plotting is an M-by-N-by-3 matrix, it's already an RGB image.
- If the image is an M-by-N matrix and has an associated colormap, use the [IND2RGB](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/ind2rgb.html) function to convert it to an RGB image.
- If the image is an M-by-N matrix with no colormap, then [IMSHOW](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/imshow.html) will still display it using the figure colormap. To convert it to an RGB image, first apply whatever windowing you want to the 2-D image data, then replicate the data in the third dimension to make it an M-by-N-by-3 matrix. Here's an example (assuming `img` is your image data):

  ```
  limits = [0.05 0.4];  %# The window you want to apply to the data
  img = (img-limits(1))./diff(limits);  %# Scale the data
  img(img < 0) = 0;  %# Clip the data outside 0 and 1 (even without these two
  img(img > 1) = 1;  %#   steps, IMSHOW should display the data properly)
  img = repmat(img,[1 1 3]);  %# Replicate the image so it is 3-D
  imshow(img);  %# Display the image
  ```

Once you've converted and plotted the image and plotted your patches as above, you should be able to use a jet colormap for the patches like so:

```
colormap(jet);
caxis(hAx,[0 25]);
```

Comment: Well I tried to set the image to RGB but it is a medic dicom image and I cannot window the image how I want if it is in true color as opposed to grayscale.

Comment: @Ben: How were you originally windowing it?

Comment: Im reading it in using dicomread and then converting it to grayscale and then using imshow('im', [0.05 0.4]).

Comment: There is no map for the dicom image when I use dicomread so I cant use ind2rgb unless I am using the function wrong.

Comment: @BenFossen: I've updated my answer to accommodate whatever type of image matrix you might be dealing with.